# Converting javascript object to JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have an application that I'm migrating away from PHP to Node.js. This application sends a javascript object as data to an ajax function that calls a PHP handler.

The PHP handler then converts the object to JSON using PHP's json_encode function. Node has a package called "json_encode" but it does not work the same as its PHP counterpart.

Basically, I want to convert this:

```
{ 'pages[anycast][blocks][0][frames_content]': ' \n <section class="bg-white builder-bg padding-110px-tb xs-padding-60px-tb" . . . }
```

into this:

```
{"pages":{"anycast":{"blocks":[{"frames_content":"            \n            <section class=\"bg-white builder-bg padding-110px-tb xs-padding-60px-tb\" . . .}
```

Using JSON.stringify(data) on the client-side before sending it over to the server creates this:

```
{ '{"data":{"pages":{"anycast":{"blocks":[{"frames_content":" \n <section class': '\\"bg-white builder-bg padding-110px-tb xs-padding-60px-tb\\" . . . }
```

which adds extra backslashes and incorrectly replaced the equal sign after

**Client-Side Code:**

```
var pages = {}, theSite;
            if( site.sitePages[0].blocks.length !== 0 ) {
                for( var x = 0; x < site.sitePages.length; x++ ) {
                    if( site.sitePages[x].blocks.length !== 0 ) {
                        pages[site.sitePages[x].name] = site.sitePages[x].prepForSave();
                    } else {                
                        pages[site.sitePages[x].name] = 'empty';
                    }
                }

                theSite = {
                    pages: pages
                };

            } else {
                theSite = {
                    delete: true
                };
            }

            //remove old alerts
            $('#errorModal .modal-body > *, #successModal .modal-body > *').each(function(){
                $(this).remove();
            });

            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://api.handler.com/save',
                method: 'POST',
                data: theSite,
                dataType: "json"
            }).done(function (res) {
                //enable button
                $("a#savePage").removeClass('disabled');
                if( res.responseCode === 0 ) {
                    if( showConfirmModal ) {
                        $('#errorModal .modal-body').html( res.responseHTML );
                        $('#errorModal').modal('show');
                    }
                } else if( res.responseCode === 1 ) {
                    //no more pending changes
                    site.setPendingChanges(false);
                    $('body').trigger('changePage');
                }
            });
        },

        /*
            preps the site data before sending it to the server
        */
        prepForSave: function(template) {
            this.sitePagesReadyForServer = {};
            if( template ) {//saving template, only the activePage is needed
                this.sitePagesReadyForServer[this.activePage.name] = this.activePage.prepForSave();
                this.activePage.fullPage();
            } else {//regular save
                //find the pages which need to be send to the server
                for( var i = 0; i < this.sitePages.length; i++ ) {
                    if( this.sitePages[i].status !== '' ) {
                        this.sitePagesReadyForServer[this.sitePages[i].name] = this.sitePages[i].prepForSave();
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

I'm sending "theSite" variable to the server via AJAX.

**Original PHP Server-side Handler:**

```
<?php
$return = [];

if( isset($_POST['data']) && $_POST['data'] != '' ) {

    if( isset($_POST['data']['delete']) ) {

        $myfile = fopen("site.json", "w");
        fwrite($myfile, '{}');
        fclose($myfile);

    } else {

        $myfile = fopen("site.json", "w");
        fwrite($myfile, json_encode($_POST['data']));
        fclose($myfile);

    }

    $return['responseCode'] = 1;
    $return['responseHTML'] = '<h5>Hooray!</h5> <p>The site was saved successfully!</p>';

} else {

    $return['responseCode'] = 0;
    $return['responseHTML'] = '<h5>Ouch!</h5> <p>Something went wrong and the site could not be saved :(</p>';

}
echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

Comment: Looks like you are serializing it as string, not as object. Therefore those extra characters. Can you provide us some code?

Comment: Where is pages[anycast][blocks][0][frames_content] being generated - client-side in JS and you're trying to get it into JSON to be sent to PHP, or server-side in PHP and you're trying to read it in JS?

Comment: Don't think it answers your question directly, but may be worth checking out lodash's [set](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#set) and [setWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#setWith) functions.

Comment: Show your original PHP code and the Node.js code that's trying to replace it. Then we can show you where you went wrong in the conversion.

Comment: Your original conversion looks like the kind of parsing that's done by PHP with POST or GET parameters. I don't think there's any built-in JS function that exposes this parsing, but it's presumably done internally in the `requests` module.

Comment: Barmar - I think you're right. I was hoping there was some native JS equivalent to do the same thing PHP does.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** I'll keep the initial answer in case it's useful for anyone else.

If you send JSON via Ajax, and you check for `$_POST['data']`, all you need to do in the PHP side is to `json_decode($_POST['data'])`.

At that time you'll have a PHP `stdClass` object with all fields you expect, such as `$object->delete` or others.

If you prefer to have associative arrays instead of objects, use `json_decode($_POST['data'], true)`.

If this is still not the answer, maybe you can better elaborate what is the exact input, and the exact output you expect, as my previous answer was about that, exactly the I/O you described.

---

Assuming there are no fancy chars in the objects keys you are receiving, as inside keys such as `'pages[anycast][blocks][0][frames_content]'`, you can use some specialized convention to convert those kind of keys (usually coming from old DBs or services that didn't know JSON already) into more recursive data.

This is just one example:

```js
const input = {'pages[anycast][blocks][0][frames_content]': 'value'};
const output = Object.keys(input).reduce(
  (js, key) => {
    let root = js;
    const keys = key
      .replace(
        /(\[|\]\[?)/g,
        ($0, $1) => $1 === ']' ? '' : '\x01'
      )
      .split('\x01');
    for (let i = 1, {length} = keys; i < length; i++) {
      const prev = keys[i - 1];
      if (!root.hasOwnProperty(prev))
        root[prev] = /^\d+$/.test(keys[i]) ? [] : {};
      root = root[prev];
    }
    root[keys.pop()] = input[key];
    return js;
  },
  {}
);
```

The serialized `output` variable will look, after the parsing, like this:

```js
{
  "pages": {
    "anycast": {
      "blocks": [
        {
          "frames_content": "value"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The current example assumes anything placed in `[0]` or `[1]` should be handled as Array, and everything else as object field.

The suggested conversion makes it possible to also have multiple entries per indexes:

```js
const input = {
  'pages[anycast][blocks][0][frames_content]': 'first',
  'pages[anycast][blocks][1][frames_content]': 'second',
};

// ... after previous parsing, output will be
{
  "pages": {
    "anycast": {
      "blocks": [
        {
          "frames_content": "first"
        },
        {
          "frames_content": "second"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, if you have twice the same field names, these will be overwritten, but I believe that should never be the case if your object comes from old services, as I think they already figured out their own schema.

Comment: Your answer produced the following result:

Comment: { pages: 
{ anycast: { blocks: [Array] },
error: { blocks: [Array] },
download: { blocks: [Array] },
check: { blocks: [Array] },
index: { blocks: [Array] },
voice: { blocks: [Array] },
home: { blocks: [Array] },
dental: { blocks: [Array] },
callonly: { blocks: [Array] } } }

Comment: I have provided an answer with the little input I had, if there was a better input there would've been a better answer. You edited the post after my answer though, so maybe I'll have a look and see what I can do.